# How can I get text of parent link while link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I click on the link A1-810 I am getting text A1-810 in anchortext variable. Now I want is when I **click on A1-810** I should also **get text ICONIA A-SERIES** in parenttext or another variable

**if A1-810 link is clicked I am getting output as**

A1-810

**Now I want output as**

A1-810

ICONIA A-SERIES

Jquery code to get the text of the link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".list-unstyled a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // don't follow the link
  var anchortext = $(this).text();
  var parenttext;
  console.log(anchortext)
 });
});
```

HTML CODE.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">ICONIA A-SERIES</a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="#">A1-810</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">A1-820</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">ICONIA B-SERIES</a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="#">B1-710</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">B1-720</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">LIQUID</a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="">A1-S100</a> </li>
      <li><a href="">Z200</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
var parenttext = $(this).closest("ul").prev("a").text();
```

Use `.closest("ul")` to travel up to find the first `ul`.
Then use `.prev("a")` to get the previous sibling of the element type `a(link)`.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list-unstyled a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't follow the link
    var anchortext = $(this).text();
    var parenttext = $(this).closest("ul").prev("a").text();
    console.log(anchortext,parenttext)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">ICONIA A-SERIES</a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="#">A1-810</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">A1-820</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">ICONIA B-SERIES</a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="#">B1-710</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">B1-720</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">LIQUID</a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="">A1-S100</a> </li>
      <li><a href="">Z200</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @UmarNazaket No problem, happy to help

Comment: Now I have to get the text of its parent. Let me add another question and share HTML with you.

Comment: @UmarNazaket Added an answer to it. Take a look at let me know if there is any problems with it.